# Cast decimal real to double precision produces strange behavior

Tags: postgresql, casting, precision, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to cast a decimal **real** to **double precision** and it has the following behavior:

```
select 2.2::real::double precision;
```

Outputs:

```
2.20000004768372 (double precision)
```

How can I make it output the following:

```
2.2 (double precision)
```

Thank you

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name), nice reading.

I solved my problem by casting to text before converting to double:

```
select 2.2::real::text::double precision;
```

That outputs:

```
2.2 (double precision)
```

And for future reference, if you must use **double precision**, you shouldn't mix it with **real**.